# How do I import globals in Postman

Tags: postman

My team has just started using Team Syncing in Postman which seems to be a great feature, but we want to be able to share the large set of global variables we use within our collections.

These are not synced to the cloud server and there doesn't seem to be a way to import them.

Has any got a good way to share these throughout the team without everyone manually entering each one?

Answer (score 13):

To share globals in Postman:

1. Export as JSON, share JSON file
2. Import globals from JSON

The same steps in more detail:

1. To export as JSON:

   a) Go to gear in upper right-hand corner, choose `Manage Environments` from the dropdown

   b) Click `Globals` button

   c) Choose `Download as JSON`
   [image: download Globals as JSON]
2. To import from JSON:

   a) Choose `Import` from upper left of Postman window
   [image: choose import]

   b) Select your JSON file or drag it into the resulting window:
   [image: select json that contains globals]

> NOTE: Even though this window says it only imports collections, environments, data dumps, curl commands, and RAML/WADL/Swagger/Runscope, it will also work for globals.

c) Click `Open` in the system dialog box (after choosing file). Your globals will be imported. You may receive an error along with the confirmation message, but the globals were still imported.
[image: confirmation and error]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a backup of the collections that the postman saves, by checking

[To get the Postman storage location](http://chrome://indexeddb-internals/)

Search for 
chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/

The location given under Paths is the one that contains all the data. For eg: /home/xyz/.config/chromium/Default/Storage/ext/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/def

Using this, the collections also can be transferred from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Postman Version 9.31.0 (9.31.0)]

In the current version (Version 9.31.0).

I find the number 1 & 2 depicted below is the way to export the environment fully to a JSON file.

The steps 3 & 4 in that order is for importing. Now, watch out for duplicates after importing as I find they aren't replaced, instead anew created and you may want to delete older/un-used versions of the same.